# Returning images/HTML using custom URI protocol on Android

Tags: android

I'm wondering if it's possible to return web content through Android's ability to register custom URI protocols for launching apps, rather than launching the app itself, such that myapp://images/logo.png will return the image logo.png to a WebView

I'm working on a tool for a company to open document libraries in Android. The libraries are just zip files with HTML, images, XML, etc.. The desktop version uses a custom URI protocol handler already, so as a result all the HTML files in the library are hard-coded to use it.

Is there any way of implementing this? I'd rather not modify the DOM on load by injecting JavaScript, but from searching around it seems like the only way. Hopefully someone here will be able to tell me otherwise.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Something similar to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854966/android-how-to-reference-asset-images-from-a-remotely-loaded-html-page-in-webvie But unfortunately, not works as expected.

Comment: Yeah, it's not quite what I'm looking for sadly, but it might help if I end up traversing the DOM with a mass find/replace. So thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it's possible to return web content through Android's ability to register custom URI protocols for launching apps, rather than launching the app itself, such that myapp://images/logo.png will return the image logo.png to a WebView

Only if `myapp` is replaced by `content` and if `images` is an authority for a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Yeah, that's my alternative solution. The problem is, I have no control over generation of html files, and they have the desktop viewer's protocol already in them. From that I'm guessing my only option is to replace them all in each HTML file by injecting Javascript to mess with the DOM?

Comment: @Daniel Brierton: Yes. Leastways, I know of no other solution.