# android webview loading remote html file with local javascript file

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview

I have to load a remote url in to my webview. It was taking too much time to load because of the size of script files included..

So i copied those js files in to my android "assets" folder tried to load them from the remote page like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/myfile.js"></script>
```

the page loads, but the javascript is not working.. any solutions??

Answer (score 4):

It is really hard to do what you want to do. You'll probably need to write some Java code in order to handle this. Check out this other SO answer.

[Android: How to reference asset images from a remotely loaded html page in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854966/android-how-to-reference-asset-images-from-a-remotely-loaded-html-page-in-webvi)

Answer (score -1):

If you forgot to enable Javascript for your WebView then set it by using:

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

And yes, post your full code that you are trying with.

Comment: No, javascript is enabled. I just found out that we cant load a local assset from a remote webpage.. thanks