# Android webview Inject javascript with local image

Tags: javascript, android, image, webview, code-injection

I have a android webview. I am loading a remote page, for example: google.com using the standard `WebView.loadUrl(url)`;

Once the page loads, `onPageFinished()`, I inject javascript like below...

```
WebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
"document.getElementById('elementid').style.backgroundImage='file:///android_asset/newbackgroundimage.png';" +
"})()");
```

Javascript injection works fine but the problem is it does not load the background image from a local assests folder. If I supply remote image URL it works fine, but I have an image locally and need to use that in the injection.

Could someone please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set settings for you WebView?

```
WebSettings webviewsettings = WebView.getSettings();
    webviewsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webviewsettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

if theres a Problem with accessing the png you could try:

```
try 
{
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("newbackgroundimage.png");
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException ex) 
{
    return;
}
```

Happy conding

Comment: i am not trying to set the background image of the webview but the background image of a certain html element.

Comment: sorry, maybe `document.getElementById('elementid').setAttribute("style","background-url:'file:///android_asset/newbackgroundimage.png')` ?

Comment: you could try using the raw dir (/res/raw). Access the file android.resource://com.packagename.sample/raw/newbackgroundimage.png

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to encode the image as base64 into a variable, avoid messing with the local filesystem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, I am working on something like this and gone through this post 
[Android: How to reference asset images from a remotely loaded html page in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854966/android-how-to-reference-asset-images-from-a-remotely-loaded-html-page-in-webvi?rq=1)

You can use loadDataWithBaseURL() for local asset images.